# How to get the reference of all elements in a div in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a `div` with 10 HTML elements. How could I get the reference of all these 10 elements and toggle a class on them on click?

```
<div>
 <some-element class="hawk"></some-element>
 <some-element class="hawk"></some-element>
 <some-element class="hawk"></some-element>
 <some-element class="hawk"></some-element>
 <some-element class="hawk"></some-element>
...
</div>
<div class="trigger" (click)="detach()">Detach</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.hawk {
    display: block;
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    &.mock {
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
 }
```

I can do this very easily by using jQuery as follows:

```
detach() {
  $('.hawk').toggleClass('mock');
}
```

What is the angular way of doing it? I tried using the @ViewChild and access the parent `div` but I was unable to add the `class` to all the child elements. While changing the `border-radius` to `0px`, is there a way to animate from the set `10px` to `0px` in `CSS` or using Angular animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @tjadli mentioned, `@ViewChildren` is the way to go. But I think his toggling logic is a bit convoluted. You can simply do the following:

```
@ViewChildren('hawk', {read: ElementRef}) ref: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

HTML:

```
<div>
 <some-element #hawk class="hawk"></some-element>
 <some-element #hawk class="hawk"></some-element>
 <some-element #hawk class="hawk"></some-element>
 <some-element #hawk class="hawk"></some-element>
 <some-element #hawk class="hawk"></some-element>
...
</div>
<div class="trigger" (click)="detach()">Detach</div>
```

Function:

```
detach() {
  this.ref.map((eleRef) => {
  if(eleRef.nativeElement.classList.contains('hawk')) {
    eleRef.nativeElement.classList.toggle('mock');
  }
 });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

First of all instead of using ViewChild you have to use ViewChildren

```
detach() {
    this.hawks.map((elmRef) => {
       if(elmRef.nativeElement.className === 'hawk') {
          elmRef.nativeElement.className = '';
       } else {
          elmRef.nativeElement.className = 'hawk';
       }
    })
}
```

and for your viewchildren :

```
@ViewChildren('hawk', {read: ElementRef}) hawks: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

and your html :

```
<some-element #hawk class="hawk"></some-element>
<some-element #hawk class="hawk"></some-element>
<some-element #hawk class="hawk"></some-element>
```

Comment: Great answer, but you should have simplified your toggling logic a bit ;)